# Ionic Barcode Scanner (Display Custom Html)

Tags: ionic-framework

I have implemented a barcode scanner using (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner). How can I display a custom HTML at the top as shown in the image below on the camera stream?

[image: Custom Html with description]

Comment: You want to achieve the effect as the image shown, or what?

Comment: I want to show that box at the top which say (Scan Qr Code Scan QR code to get discount), Currently I have a plane barcode scanner

Comment: please my project as reference (https://github.com/tomfong/simple-qr)